# Question on combining 2 datasets with common key

Tags: dataset

Hi I'm trying to combine 2 datasets with a common key which I'm not able to resolve with JoinAcross. 1st dataset is

```
names = Dataset[{
            <|"UID" -> "UID1", "FN" -> "FirstName1", "LN" -> "LastName1"|>,
            <|"UID" -> "UID2", "FN" -> "FirstName2", "LN" -> "LastName2"|>,
            <|"UID" -> "UID3", "FN" -> "FirstName3", "LN" -> "LastName3"|>,
            <|"UID" -> "UID4", "FN" -> "FirstName4", "LN" -> "LastName4"|>,
            <|"UID" -> "UID5", "FN" -> "FirstName5", "LN" -> "LastName5"|>}];
```

and the second dataset is

```
records = Dataset[{<|"UID1" -> "record1"|>, 
                    <|"UID1" -> "record2"|>, 
                    <|"UID1" -> "record3"|>,
                    <|"UID3" -> "record4"|>,
                    <|"UID3" -> "record5"|> ,
                    <|"UID3" -> "record6"|> ,
                    <|"UID5" -> "record7"|> }];
```

I'm trying to get a combined dataset which would look like this:

```
wanted = Dataset[{
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName1", "LN" -> "LastName1", "UID1" -> "record1"|>, 
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName1", "LN" -> "LastName1", "UID1" -> "record2"|>, 
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName1", "LN" -> "LastName1", "UID1" -> "record3"|>,
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName3", "LN" -> "LastName3", "UID3" -> "record4"|>,
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName3", "LN" -> "LastName3", "UID3" -> "record5"|> ,
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName3", "LN" -> "LastName3", "UID3" -> "record6"|> ,
    <|"FN" -> "FirstName5", "LN" -> "LastName5", "UID5" -> "record7"|> }];
```

In other words, I'm trying to get names from userID in first data set tied to full name and records in 2nd dataset.

JoinAcross is of no help. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Gani -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
names = {<|"UID" -> "UID1", "FN" -> "FirstName1", 
    "LN" -> "LastName1"|>, <|"UID" -> "UID2", "FN" -> "FirstName2", 
    "LN" -> "LastName2"|>, <|"UID" -> "UID3", "FN" -> "FirstName3", 
    "LN" -> "LastName3"|>, <|"UID" -> "UID4", "FN" -> "FirstName4", 
    "LN" -> "LastName4"|>, <|"UID" -> "UID5", "FN" -> "FirstName5", 
    "LN" -> "LastName5"|>};

records = {<|"UID1" -> "record1"|>, <|"UID1" -> "record2"|>, <|
    "UID1" -> "record3"|>, <|"UID3" -> "record4"|>, <|
    "UID3" -> "record5"|>, <|"UID3" -> "record6"|>, <|
    "UID5" -> "record7"|>};

names = Association[#UID -> # & /@ names]

records = First@Normal@# & /@ records

f2[x0_] := 
 With[{uid = x0[[1]]}, <|"FN" -> names[uid]["FN"], 
   "LN" -> names[uid]["LN"], uid -> x0[[2]]|>]

wanted = f2 /@ records
```

Skip the wrapping of `Dataset`, it will not help with your non-normalized datastructure, and it general, wrapping with `Dataset` is only helpful for display of final output

Comment: thanks for the elegant solution. Now, I need to step through it to digest what you've done! gani-

Comment: Using `Composition`. `records = First@*Normal /@ records`.

Comment: @GaniGanapathi Please don't hesitate to ask for help! All the best